# How to find the maximum value in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, max

In java, i need to be able to go through an array and find the max value. How would I compare the elements of the array to find the max?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: We're not here to do homework for you.

Comment: Im sorry i figured it out and i forgot to put my code up their but im fine now

Comment: I found this solution very effective using javascript `function myArrayMax(arr) {
    return Math.min.apply(null, arr);
}`

Answer (score 17):

Have a max int and set it to the first value in the array. Then in a for loop iterate through the whole array and see if the max int is larger than the int at the current index.

```
int max = array.get(0);

for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array.get(i) > max) {
      max = array.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: create a max variable decalre it to zero. if the

Comment: if it is an ArrayList it is `arraylist.get(0)` if it an array it is `array[0]`

Answer (score 15):

If you can change the order of the elements:

```
 int[] myArray = new int[]{1, 3, 8, 5, 7, };
 Arrays.sort(myArray);
 int max = myArray[myArray.length - 1];
```

If you can't change the order of the elements:

```
int[] myArray = new int[]{1, 3, 8, 5, 7, };
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if(myArray[i] > max) {
         max = myArray[i];
      }
}
```

Comment: Sorting is a bad idea unless performance is of no concern. Sorting is O(n log n) whereas iterating over the array once is only O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the Array. First initialize the maximum value to the first element of the array and then for each element optimize it if the element under consideration is greater.