# Max element of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, max

Ok so I'm trying to find the largest element in an array, and I realize this is not the best method to do this, it only works in some cases. Would appreciate some pointers on how to change my code so it works for all instances.

```
public static int maxArray(int[] a) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length-1; j++) {
        if (a[j+1] > a[j]) {
            max = a[j+1];
        } else {
            max = a[j];
        }

    }
    return max;

}
```

Comment: Here is related question [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/java-max-min-value-in-an-array) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325168/how-would-i-find-the-maximum-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do it like so,

Start with `max = a[0];` then loop with `j` from `1` to `a.length`.
Compare `a[j]` to `max`, that is if `a[j] > max` then set `max = a[j];`.

Comment: The only other suggestion I have is to handle null and the empty array. That is `if (a == null || a.length == 0) return null;`

Answer (score 2):

Use this method.

```
public static int maxArray(int[] a) {

int max = a[0]; // saves a bit of time

for (int j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {
    if (a[j] > max) {
        max = a[j];
    }

}
return max;
```

}

This is pretty speedy and concise.

Comment: I would start your loop at `j = 1`, loop until `j < a.length`, and check if `a[j] > max`.

Comment: actually by adding the if check, you have made the `saves a bit of time` a bit more expensive than starting at index `0` and using `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as initial max

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the current element with maximum element, not with the next one.

```
if (a[j] > max) {
    max = a[j];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 You can use Stream:

```
public static int maxArray(int[] a) {
    return Arrays.stream(a).max().getAsInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T maxArray(T[] array) {
    return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(array));
}
```

after you make calls to the function, eg:

> Integer[] a = { 1, 5, -6, 3, 0, 2 };
>
> Integer max = maxArray(a);
>
> System.out.println(max);

Comment: Note that this is an `int[]` and not a `T[]`. This will not work. Also note that the `Object` in `T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>` is redundant.

Comment: for redundancy, the declaration of the max function is: `public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)`

Comment: I assume you copied this from the [source of `Collections`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.max%28java.util.Collection%29). It is there for [backwards compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19488411/2071828). There is no reason to have it in your example.

Comment: yes, `<T extends Comparable>` and add a cast to return : `(T)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getMaxElement(int[] elements) {
    int max = elements[0];
    for (int j = 0; j < elements.length-1; j++) {
        if (elements[j] > max) {
            max = elements[j];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```