# How to find the largest value from an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program which can tracking three dices' total appears.Here are my codes:

```
import java.util.*;

class dice{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] track = new int[19];

        for (int roll=0; roll<10000; roll++){
            int sum=0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                //roll the 6-face dice
                int n = rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
                sum+=n;
            }
            ++track[sum];
        }

        System.out.println("Sum\tFrequency");

        for(int finalSum=3; finalSum<track.length;finalSum++){
            System.out.println(finalSum+"\t"+track[finalSum]);
        }
        System.out.println("the largest frequency is %d", //how to find it?)
    }
}
```

Now I am almost done. But how can I find the largest appearance and print it separately? Thank you.

Comment: Please see:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806816/java-finding-the-highest-value-in-an-array
Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325168/how-would-i-find-the-maximum-value-in-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
System.out.println("Min value "+arr[0]);
System.out.println("Max value "+arr[arr.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int largest(int[] myArr) {
    int largest = myArr[0];
    for(int num : myArr) {
        if(largest < num) {
            largest = num;
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Set the variable `largest` to the first item in the array. Loop over the array, whenever the current `num` you're in is bigger than the current `largest` value, set largest to `num`.